# MongoDB - Grouping/aggregating of records with matched fields only when they're continuous, sorted by time

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that looks something like this:

```
[{ 
"_id" : ..., 
"name" : "bla", 
"type" : "A", 
"time" : NumberInt(1)
},
{ 
"_id" : ..., 
"name" : "bla", 
"type" : "A", 
"time" : NumberInt(2)
},
{ 
"_id" : ..., 
"name" : "bla", 
"type" : "A", 
"time" : NumberInt(3)
},
{ 
"_id" : ..., 
"name" : "cla", 
"type" : "B", 
"time" : NumberInt(4)
},
{ 
"_id" : ..., 
"name" : "cla", 
"type" : "A", 
"time" : NumberInt(5)
},
{ 
"_id" : ..., 
"name" : "bla", 
"type" : "A", 
"time" : NumberInt(6)
}]
```

I want to sort by time, then group based on "name" and form a list of types, but only for contiguous records with same name(in time). The result I want needs to look something like below:

```
[{
    "_id": "....",
    "name": "bla",
    "types": ["A", "A", "A"],
    "start_time": 1,
    "end_time": 3
},
{
    "_id": "....",
    "name": "cla",
    "types": ["B", "A"],
    "start_time": 4,
    "end_time": 5
},
{
    "_id": "....",
    "name": "bla",
    "types": ["A"],
    "start_time": 6,
    "end_time": 6
}]
```

The only way I've been able to achieve this so far is to iterate through each record and checking if the name has changed. I've tried using aggregate and group, but I've not found a way to group only continuous records as above. Is there a way to us the aggregation framework to achieve this result ?